# 'String or binary data would be truncated.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16'

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pymssql

I am trying to insert data into the SQL Server Table using `pymssql`. My code for that is as below:

```
def main():
    out = get_sql()
    print("%s Batches to be exported" %(len(out)))
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        for batch, i in enumerate(executor.map(scoring_and_loading, out)):
            try:
                conn = pymssql.connect(server="SQLDev02",database="DEVDB", user='', password='')
                curr = conn.cursor()
                query =  "INSERT INTO [dbo].[STG_CONTACTABILITY_SCORE] VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
                sql_data = list(map(tuple,i.values))
                curr.executemany(query, sql_data)
                conn.commit()
                print("Batch %s exported" %(batch))
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

`STG_CONTACTABILITY_SCORE` definition is as follows:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[STG_CONTACTABILITY_SCORE](
    [RecordType] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [ContactName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [AccountName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [ContactabilityScore] [int] NULL,
    [PreferredPhoneNumber] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [PreferredCallerId] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [DoubleDialRecommended] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [DayofTheWeek] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [CallBlockStartTime] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [CallBlockEndTime] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [Season] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [CallDuration] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [DialNumber] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Cumulative#ofAttempts] [int] NULL,
    [LastUpdatedDate] [date] NULL,
    [LoadDate] [date] NULL,
    [LoadStatus] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [LoadNumber] [int] NULL,
    [ContactId] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TimeZone] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [BatchNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [AccountId] [varchar](20) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

The information about the data frame I'm trying to inserting into the table is as follows:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 9800 entries, 0 to 9799
Data columns (total 22 columns):
RecordType               9800 non-null object
ContactName              9800 non-null object
AccountName              9800 non-null object
ContactabilityScore      9800 non-null float64
PreferredPhoneNumber     9800 non-null object
PreferredCallerId        0 non-null object
DoubleDialRecommended    0 non-null object
DayofTheWeek             9800 non-null object
CallBlockStartTime       9800 non-null object
CallBlockEndTime         9800 non-null object
Season                   9800 non-null object
CallDuration             0 non-null object
DialNumber               0 non-null object
Cumulative#ofAttempts    0 non-null object
LastUpdatedDate          9800 non-null object
LoadDate                 9800 non-null object
LoadStatus               9800 non-null object
LoadNumber               0 non-null object
ContactId                9800 non-null object
TimeZone                 9800 non-null object
BatchNumber              0 non-null object
AccountId                9800 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), object(21)
```

I checked whether there is any value in `AccountName` or `ContactName` whose length is larger than 100 and didn't find any. I am not able to understand what am I doing wrong. I will much appreciate your help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: where is the error message?

Comment: where is the actual data to be inserted?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu: the error message is the topic of this question. **'String or binary data would be truncated.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16'**

Comment: Will the head of the data frame do for you? It is not possible to post the entire data frame here

Comment: table columns are 22, insert columns are 22... question, is your mapping in the correct order?

Comment: yes, they are mapped in the correct order.

Comment: good,..good luck you'll need it

Comment: The column `ContactabilityScore` is `float64` in your dataframe and you are trying to stuff that into an `int` (32) column in your table. That might be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your table schema. In my case, I defined column **abc varchar(55)** and values length was **125**. Ensure your data length, datatype you defined.